# Reversing default Java LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I can write my own LinkedList and reverse it. But I am not able to reverse default java.util.LinkedList

My problem is how to do something like the following for java.util.LinkedList

```
while (CurrentNode != NULL)
{ 
    Node NextNode = CurrentNode.next;
    CurrentNode.next = PreviousNode;

/*  repeat the process, but have to reset
     the PreviousNode and CurrentNode
*/

PreviousNode = CurrentNode;
CurrentNode = NextNode;  
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to reverse a linked list, since it can be iterated in both directions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#descendingIterator%28%29

Comment: In addition to @JBNizet comment, you might want to see this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27742/How-To-Reverse-a-Linked-List-Different-Ways

Comment: @hagubear What is LinkedListNode in the examples in the link you shared ?

Comment: @Andy897 The name is pretty clear in itself... It is a node of the linked list.

Comment: @Dici My point is it is not there by default in Java.util.LinkedList

Comment: @JBNizet  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945886/java-converting-list-to-object-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Collections.reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) will do it for you.

```
import java.util.Collections;

// in your function
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Regarding doing it manually, you don't have access to the internal representation of the java.util.LinkedList so you can't do it manually using the public interface.

Comment: Such a short and undetailed (even if relevant) answer should be a comment

Comment: @Andy897 look at the code of Collections.reverse(), which comes with the JDK, and you'll know.

Comment: @Dici No, this is a complete answer to the question. There is no more detail to add.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike an example in C where every node has a pointer to another node, Java LinkedList wont provide the pointer/reference to the next node. All these things are handled internally and abstracted from the programmer. This seems to be the only way to reverse it with the least effort.

Java Collections internally has a efficient algorithm to sort the list so that you dont have to worry about these details.

Use Java collections to manipulate Lists and Sets. Here's a simple code snippet

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>(){{
            add(5);
            add(8);
            add(3);
            add(7);
            add(1);
        }};

        System.out.println(myList);
        Collections.reverse(myList);
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```